# Creating centralized DBA database

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have 200+ servers and I am thinking about creating a centralized DBA database where it logs backup, errors, space jobs and generate reports on SSRS. I am not sure where to start and I would highly appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I accomplish this using System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2? Please let me know from your experience comparing to MOM. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

On SQL Server 2008 R2 I'd guide you to [SQL Server Utility Control Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210548.aspx), with some details [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/multi_server_administration_p1.aspx).

From MSDN description:
"The SQL Server Utility models an organization’s SQL Server-related entities in a unified view. Utility Explorer and SQL Server Utility viewpoints in (SSMS) provide administrators a holistic view of resource health through an instance of SQL Server that serves as a utility control point (UCP). Entities that can be viewed in the SQL Server UCP include:

```
Instances of SQL Server
Data-tier applications
Database files
Storage volumes
```

Resource utilization dimensions that can be viewed in the SQL Server UCP include:

```
CPU utilization
Storage space utilization"
```

On 2008 and earlier - MOM, as Gaius pointed, or maybe give a try to [Multi Server Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180992%28SQL.100%29.aspx) as defined by MS. You can see detailed article on SQLServerCentral [Multi-Server Administration](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/multiserveradministration/675/) or on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191305%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [MOM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=79F151C7-4D98-4C2B-BF72-EC2B4AE69191&displaylang=en#QuickDetails), MS's product for doing this. It is broadly analogous to Oracle's [Grid Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/index.html).

Comment: I didn't know MOM is free. Have you used it before? do you know a good blog post on how to implement it? Thank you.

Comment: MOM is very much not free.  You have to purchase the server license as well as a license for each server that MOM is monitoring.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a SQL2008 machine to use, look into the using `Central Management Server`. It is free and built into SQL. You can even do `multiserver queries` and `policy based management`. [Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to develop smth custom where you can log what info you want take these steps as start:
Create tables with servers, databases linked to server  id, backup info linked both to server id and db id. Create scripts that will be launched on destination servers using xp_cmdshell. The scripts will insert collected info to destination tempdb table and insert through linked server to your DBA server.  This is very shortly. you can contact me on private if you need more details. I am using this method as it is the best way to track many stuff.